# Should I downvote a question that I am also voting to close or put on hold?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, vote-to-close

Sometimes I see a question that might have potential, but in the current wording is a question that should be voted closed/on hold.

Should I downvote the question in addition to casting a close vote?

In what cases (if there is any) should I take both actions?

Answer (score 7):

From the help center:

> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy,
>   no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps
>   dangerously incorrect.

Just because a question isn't fitting for this site, such as being too broad or off-topic, doesn't mean you should downvote. Downvotes are a way of marking a post as effectively trash, and aren't in the same spirit as a vote to close.